# How to convert a Task<TDerived> to a Task<TBase>?

Tags: c#, task, async-await

Since C#'s Task is a class, you obviously can't cast a `Task<TDerived>` to a `Task<TBase>`.

However, you can do:

```
public async Task<TBase> Run() {
    return await MethodThatReturnsDerivedTask();
}
```

Is there a static task method I can call to get a `Task<TDerived>` instance which essentially just points to the underlying task and casts the result? I'd like something like:

```
public Task<TBase> Run() {
    return Task.FromDerived(MethodThatReturnsDerivedTask());
}
```

Does such a method exist? Is there any overhead to using an async method solely for this purpose?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Does such a method exist?

No.

> Is there any overhead to using an async method solely for this purpose?

Yes. But it's the easiest solution.

Note that a more generic approach is an extension method for `Task` such as `Then`. Stephen Toub explored this [in a blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-then-with-await/) and I've recently [incorporated it into AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TaskExtensions&referringTitle=Documentation).

Using `Then`, your code would look like:

```
public Task<TBase> Run()
{
  return MethodThatReturnsDerivedTask().Then(x => (TBase)x);
}
```

Another approach with slightly less overhead would be to create your own `TaskCompletionSource<TBase>` and have it completed with the derived result (using `TryCompleteFromCompletedTask` in my AsyncEx library):

```
public Task<TBase> Run()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TBase>();
  MethodThatReturnsDerivedTask().ContinueWith(
      t => tcs.TryCompleteFromCompletedTask(t),
      TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

or (if you don't want to take a dependency on AsyncEx):

```
public Task<TBase> Run()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TBase>();
  MethodThatReturnsDerivedTask().ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    if (t.IsFaulted)
      tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
    else if (t.IsCanceled)
      tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    else
      tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);
  }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return MethodThatReturnsDerivedTask().ContinueWith(task => (TBase)task.Result, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)`?

Comment: If you use `Result`, you'll wrap any exceptions in an `AggregateException` and complete faulted if the original task completed in a canceled state. That said, with some more code to handle those situations correctly, you *could* make a working solution using `ContinueWith` without `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Hi Stephen! I think that a `TaskScheduler.Default` is missing here. 

Answer (score 20):

> Does such a method exist? Is there any overhead to using an async method solely for this purpose?

There is no built-in method for this, and this does cause overhead.

The "lightest weight" alternative would be to use a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to create a new task for this.  This could be done via an extension method like so:

```
static Task<TBase> FromDerived<TBase, TDerived>(this Task<TDerived> task) where TDerived : TBase
{
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TBase>();

     task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.SetResult(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
     task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.SetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
     task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.SetCanceled(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

     return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Consider handling the exception branch by doing `SetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions)` to avoid `AggregateException` wrappers.

Comment: Do you mean to be using `TaskContinuationOptions` instead of `TaskCompletionOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this : 
`task.ContinueWith<TDerived>( t => (TDerived)t.Result);`