# How to return an instance of a derived generic class when a base class is expected using static factory methods?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, return-type

Using the Result pattern, I want to implement a ValidationBehavior using FluentValidation and MediatR. The behavior's return value should either be a `Result` or a `Result<TValue>`.

My base `Result` class looks like this:

```csharp
public class Result
{
    protected internal Result(bool isSuccess, Error error){...}

    public Error Error { get; }
    public bool IsFailure => !IsSuccess;
    public bool IsSuccess { get; }

    // some static methods to create Success and Failure results...
    // e.g.
    public static Result<TValue> Failure<TValue>(Error error)
        => error.ToResult<TValue>();
}
```

And the generic version to hold a value:

```csharp
public class Result<TValue> : Result
{
    private readonly TValue? _value;

    protected internal Result(TValue? value, bool isSuccess, Error error)
        : base(isSuccess, error)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public TValue Value => IsSuccess
                           ? _value!
                           : throw new InvalidOperationException("The value of a failure result can't be accessed.");
}
```

My `ValidationBehavior` (using MediatR) I define as:

```csharp
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
             : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
             where TRequest : IBaseRequest
             where TResponse : Result
{ }
```

Depending on the request, it either expects a plain `Result` or a `Result<TValue>` (e.g., the id of the newly created entity in the db that is returned by a command (`public interface ICommand<TResponse> : IRequest<Result<TResponse>>` (wrapper around MediatR)). Since the generic constraint  says `where TResponse : Result`, I can know only at runtime what type of `Result` is expected.

Now if the validation of a command fails (e.g., `public sealed record InsertPersonCommand(string Name, int Age) : ICommand<Guid>;`), I want to return a Result.Failure(error) but I don't know the type of TValue at compiletime.

Doing this, my code (simplified) compiles and I can run it:

```csharp
                   // : Result
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request,
                                        RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // validate

        var errors = CreateErrorsFromValidationFailures(validationFailures);

        if (errors.Any())
        {
            return (TResponse)Result.Failure(errors);
        }

        return await next();
    }
```

When my program hits the first `return`, it throws an exception because it cannot convert `MyApp.CoolNamespace.Result` (because I used the non-generic method) to `MyApp.CoolNamespace.Result<Guid>` (TResponse, expected by the command, revealed at runtime).

I have looked at ([Instantiate an object with a runtime-determined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981330/instantiate-an-object-with-a-runtime-determined-type)) and ([How to convert a Task to a Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530099/how-to-convert-a-tasktderived-to-a-tasktbase)) but I don't want to instantiate a Result nor am I dealing with `Task`s at that stage.

How can I achieve a generic solution that returns either a `Result` (e.g., in case of an UpdateCommand) or a `Result<TValue>` (see example above)?

What I want inside `if (errors.Any())` (in pseudo code):

```csharp
...
if (TResponse is generic)
{
    Type tValue = TResponse.GetTypeOfValue();

    // this doesn't work with type variables
    return Result.Failure<tValue>(errors);
}
else
{
    return Result.Failure(errors);
}
...
```

Comment: Right now the non-generic `Result` has a `Faliure` method returning the generic `Result<T>`. Is this a typo? Did you mean to declare two `Failure` methods, one for `Result` and one for `Result<T>`?

Comment: My `Result` class also has `public static Result Failure(Error error) => error.ToResult();` for a failure without a value. I omitted it from the question because I don't think it is relevant. Or do you disagree?

Comment: There's a reason it's so common to use exceptions instead of returning a value in the case of an unexpected error.  This whole pattern is a lot more work, and results in code with lots of boilerplate and is often error prone by its nature.

Comment: @Servy I bet there are reasons for it, but I don't think that my case is the prime example for it. I would like to stick to the Result pattern as I've already implemented it in the rest of my code and so far only this very scenario is giving me a headache ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the details, but are you sure your Handle method should not simply return a `Task<Result<TResponse>>` ? And use a separate method for `Task<Result>`? Going overboard with generics tend to complicate things. To bad there is no "generic void", i.e. `Task<void>`.

Comment: @JonasH Technically there is a system void class, you just can't use it yourself.  You can of course make your own (simply create a class with a private constructor you never call) if you prefer how that works over using a generic and non-generic version.

Comment: @JonasH I'm not sure if MediatR can handle (pun intended) that. I will have to check their docs and play around with it. That would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: @Servy Sure, but it wont really help with all the built in types and functions. And there is a risk that creating your own `void` would confuse and complicate more than it would help. I just think this is a (small) weakness in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# 11+, you can have static abstract interface methods.

You can declare an `IResult` interface that both `Result` types implement. `Failure` would be a static abstract method in the interface

```
public interface IResult<TSelf> {
    Error Error { get; }
    bool IsSuccess { get; }
    
    static abstract TSelf Failure(Error error);
}

public class Result: IResult<Result>
{
    // ...

    public static Result Failure(Error error)
        => ...;
}

public class Result<TValue> : IResult<Result<TValue>>
{
    // ...

    public static Result<TValue> Failure(Error error)
        => ...;
}
```

Note that `Failure` should not be generic. It can use the `TValue` type parameter declared in the class declaration.

Then in the validation behaviour, change the constraints for `TResponse` to:

```
where TResponse : IResult<TResponse>
```

In `Handle`, you can simply do

```
return TResponse.Failure(someError);
```

whenever you want to return a failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it sounds very promising. I will have to very the implementation and how much I'd have to change in the rest of my code.

Comment: I tested your suggestion and it works like a charm :) A design analyzer is giving me CA1000 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1000) but I can live with that. Thank you!

Comment: I agree with the duplicate answer and I could have made it work with one of the answers provided in that question, but I will mark this as the answer to mine, as it is more specific to my problem / the Result pattern.